# Mongoose query using different params

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user collection that looks like this, there are there two different ways it's formated:

```
{
  id: '5d5d4980133e9145fa4f85d5',
  name: 'John Doe',
  user_id: null
},
{
  id: '5d5d4980133e9145fa4f85d3',
  name: 'Jane Doe',
  user_id: jane-doe
}
```

Some have the `user_id` of null. What I want to do is, when I search by id (through params), I want first to search by the `user_id`, and if it's null, to search by `_id`.

I tried something like this:

```
User.findOne({ $or: [
  {_id: params.id},
  {user_id: params.user_id}
]})
```

It works if I search it by `_id`, but for `user_id` it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you also add your sample input and expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `user_id` is not string as I can see in JSON

```
findById(id) => {
  return User.findOne({
     user_id: id
  }).then(user => {
     if (!user) {
       return User.findById(id)
     }
     return user
  })
}
```

Here I created a method for you to search User by `user_id` and then by `id` however I would like you to have a check, if its a `ObjectID` you should skip search by `user_id` and directly search by  `_id`